# Solvability condition for diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving

A friend of mine (who does not speak English) asked me if I can help him with one of his math problems, so I am going to explain it here. *If there is something, that does not make sense anyhow, I will edit it.*

We are dealing with diophantine equations of the following type:

$$axy + cx + by = d \tag{1}\label{1}.$$

Even though it may look like a quadratic equation with constants equal to 0, in fact, it is a hyperbolic relation, where $y=(d-bx)/(ax+c)$. The following holds: if $x$ raises, $y$ decreases hyperbolically.

Basically, the equation $\ref{1}$ is derived from the following expression:

$$ (ax + b) * (ay + c) $$

in such way, that $(ax+b) = N$ and $(ay+c)= P$. Therefore, after simple adjustments, we get:

$$a^2xy+acx+aby = N*P - bc.\tag{2}\label{2}$$

After dividing \ref{2} by $a$ and providing the following substitution $\frac{N*P - bc}{a} = d$, we get the equation \ref{1}.

We can get the classic solution for equations of this type by getting the dividers of $(ad+bc)$. If $(ad+bc) = N*P$, then some of these dividers dividers (at least 2) are solutions of the equation \ref{2}. However, that's a general solution of such problem.

I have 400-600 equations of the already mentioned type and I have the concrete values of the constats $a, b, c, d$ for all of these equations. However, only few of them have a solution and I would like to know which of them these are. *Therefore, since I need to know only which of these equations are solvable, I would need to know if there exists any solvability condition of these equations in order to make my problem solving efficient.*

I state one of the concrete examples of my equations, for which I need to find out, whether there exists a solution or not. As I already mentioned, I do not care, what is the solution, but I only care, whether there's a solution for such equation:

$$a = 3\,000 , b = 667 , c = 661, d = 377 608,$$

so the equation is

$$ 3\,000xy+667x+661y = 377\,608.$$

Comment: Are you familiar with [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://brilliant.org/wiki/diophantine-equations-solve-by-factoring/#quadratic-diophantine-equations-solve-by-simons)?

Answer (score 1):

Apply SFFT:

$3000^2xy + 3000 \times 667 x + 3000 \times 661 y +667\times 661= 3000 \times 377608 + 667\times 661$
$(3000x+667)(3000y+661) = 818495$

It remains to factor the RHS and see if we can get it into the form of the LHS.

Working mod $a = 3000$ allows us to conclude that there are no solutions if we reach a contradiction. E.g. In this case, we have $2887 \equiv 2495 \pmod{3000}$, so there are no solutions.
Note that even if the modulo equation is true, it does not imply that solutions must exist.

Comment: May you clarify, please, how did you get to this congruence $2887 \equiv 2495 ($mod $ 3000)$?

Comment: @scarface What congruence did you get for $ ( 3000x + 667 ) ( 3000y + 661) \pmod{3000}$ and $818495  \pmod{3000}$?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Actually, this still does not help much well enough. We have looked over some math forums and we suppose that there does not exist and strict and precise solvability condition for this type of equations.